# Does the NEST client, or indeed elasticsearch have a facility to retry delete_by_query, in particular in case of version_conflicts?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

We are using the .NET NEST client for elasticsearch (ver 7.X)

My question is, whether there is a facility to retry the *deletebyquery* in case of version_conflicts in NEST or in ElasticSearch, or should this be the responsiblity of the calling application (by retrying if *response.version_conflicts > 0*)?

```
var client = new ElasticClient(m_ConnectionSettings);

var response = client.DeleteByQuery<ResourceSearchData>(

     q => q.Query(
     e => e.Ids(
     descriptor => descriptor.Values(
     resourcesToDelete.Select(data => data.Id)))

).WaitForCompletion());
```

Comment: i'm not aware of any built-in feature, I'm afraid you should implement the retry yourself

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs support retry_on_conflict like the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), but [Delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/docs-delete-by-query.html) is not one of them. The NEST client does not expose additional functionality in this regard. To do as much work as possible every time, I suggest you set conflicts to proceed and then continue to retry the operation as you suggested when the response indicates there were conflicts.